# Enable/Disable WPF buttons depending on the number of clicks

Tags: c#, wpf, click, paging, button

I have two buttons

'btnPrev' and 'btnNext'

What I want to do is to be able to determine the number of clicks of the button so that I could enable and disable them. The process is almost similar to 'paging' method.

Initial state: btnPrev - disabled, btnNext - enabled
1st Click (btnNext): btnPrev - enabled, btnNext - enabled
2nd Click (btnNext): btnPrev - enabled, btnNext - enabled
3rd Click (btnNext): btnPrev - enabled, btnNext - disabled

the idea is almost the same vice-versa (for btnPrev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your page number as an int.  You only need to know how many pages there are.

Then you'll have **two boundary conditions**:

- `int = 0` means prev is disabled, next is enabled.
- `int = maxPages - 1` means next is disabled, and prev is enabled.

Otherwise, both next and prev are enabled.

When they click next, increment the int by one.  When they click prev, decrement it by one.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've created a static count to determine how many clicks and used those two boundary conditions to enable and disable buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that you create a wizard with 3 pages. You might consider another design to implement this wizard, in which a Controller handles the Workflow.

The ViewModel sample application of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com) shows how this can be done.